# not able to Execute shell script containing executable through android app

Tags: java, android, shell

I have designed one android application in which i want to invoke shell script which in turn executes one executable(i have place both(script and executable) of them in assets folder).

My executable takes one argument as hex number

when i executes shell script through adb shell from my linux(ubuntu) manually, it is working fine but when application does try to execute that executable through script it is not working(***not giving even error message***).

here is script part;

```
/data/data/com.example.test/program 0x950000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android does not run in shell...

Comment: @alfasin I am running a process in android application using Runtime.exec(String command).....which invokes shell script....in that shell script i am running executable(program) with argument 0x950000 which should give output in hexadecimal.

Comment: The output of executable,i am running is in hexadecimal......and i have used inputstreamreader and bufferedreader for getting output.
is it problem because of that(because both are for characters only)???????

Comment: Latest update::::i am not able to execute the executable placed in data/data/com.example.sample folder. It is giving permission denied error.....I have tried to change it(by "su" command) through application but it is giving like """"su:uid xxxxx not allowed to su""""